# Difference between #ifdef __linux and #ifdef __unix in C++ header file

Tags: c++, coding-style, header-files, preprocessor-directive

I've seen some boilerplate header file code for dealing with different OS's, like the following:

```
#ifdef __WIN32
    //windows
#elif __linux
    //linux
#elif __unix
    //all unix not captured above
#endif
```

If `__unix` catches all unices not captured by `__linux`, why not just use `__unix`? I'm assuming it's some sort of safeguard, like "if `__linux` isn't enough, use this".

However, there has to be some reason both are used, instead of just having a catch-all with `__unix` (once again, this assumption may be wrong).

What's the deal?

Comment: The reason you can find here [OSs](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/)

Comment: unix is not the same as linux

Answer (score 0):

As have been stated in the comments Unix and Linux are two different operating systems and although a large amount of software is compatible they have a separate licensing structure. This means that a number of tools that are available in Linux are not available in Unix and vice versa. An example of this is Unix's ZFS file system which cannot be distributed under the same license as Linux and as a result support is not included in stock Linux kernels (although it is possible to compile a custom kernel with support). In terms of the particular boiler plate it is likely that it is just covering all basis and could be used to take advantage of particular tools that are available on each operating system.